# Getting positive/negative percentages from word2vec

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, gensim, word2vec

I'm playing around with Linan Qiu's [example](https://linanqiu.github.io/2015/10/07/word2vec-sentiment/) of a word2vec implementation ([Github](https://github.com/linanqiu/word2vec-sentiments)), with the final goal to analyse a bunch of tweets.

The problem I'm facing is that I have no idea on how to extract positive/negative/polarity percentages from this implementation of word2vec. The code delivers an accuracy rate so I presume it must check the predicted value (POS/NEG) against the known value (in this case an entire .txt is filled with either POS or NEG). So my approach would be to get the predicted POS/NEG rating per document(in this case per review), then of course simply add those up (the number of ratings, I mean) and divide POS and NEG from it to get a percentage. This percentage would then cover all documents in that file. From this, the polarity could perhaps also be calculated but I'm trying to figure POS/NEG out first.

Would anyone have any idea on how to get those predicted ratings? Below is the post-vectorisation code, but it's rather similar (cough) to the standard used.

Thank you so much!

```
# gensim modules
from gensim import utils
from gensim.models.doc2vec import LabeledSentence
from gensim.models import Doc2Vec

# numpy
import numpy

# shuffle
from random import shuffle

# logging
import logging
import os.path
import sys
import cPickle as pickle

# logres
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

#commit

model = Doc2Vec.load('./imdb.d2v')

train_arrays = numpy.zeros((25000, 100))
train_labels = numpy.zeros(25000)

for i in range(12500):
    prefix_train_pos = 'TRAIN_POS_' + str(i)
    prefix_train_neg = 'TRAIN_NEG_' + str(i)
    train_arrays[i] = model.docvecs[prefix_train_pos]
    train_arrays[12500 + i] = model.docvecs[prefix_train_neg]
    train_labels[i] = 1
    train_labels[12500 + i] = 0



test_arrays = numpy.zeros((25000, 100))
test_labels = numpy.zeros(25000)

for i in range(12500):
    prefix_test_pos = 'TEST_POS_' + str(i)
    prefix_test_neg = 'TEST_NEG_' + str(i)
    test_arrays[i] = model.docvecs[prefix_test_pos]
    test_arrays[12500 + i] = model.docvecs[prefix_test_neg]
    test_labels[i] = 1
    test_labels[12500 + i] = 0


classifier = LogisticRegression()
classifier.fit(train_arrays, train_labels)

print classifier.score(test_arrays, test_labels)
```

Answer (score 0):

Linan here. I just updated my repo with the latest code.

The prediction is done in the LogisticRegression step. Specifically, in https://github.com/linanqiu/word2vec-sentiments/blob/master/word2vec-sentiment.ipynb, at the lines:

`classifier = LogisticRegression()
classifier.fit(train_arrays, train_labels)`

`classifier.fit` fits the classifier created in the `LogisticRegression()` line. This classifier can then be used to predict values using the predict method described here:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html

The score method for the classifier does this behind the scenes.